# Dynamically unloading a Browser Helper Object (BHO)

Tags: winapi, atl, bho

Is there a documented way to dynamically unload a BHO on demand, even when IE is running?

I guess a brutal way such as manually calling `FreeLibrary` will work, but I hope there's a better method.

Comment: BHOs are managed by IE, and IE only. IE loads them, IE unloads them. They are not designed to be unloaded manually. Calling FreeLibrary() on a DLL that has active objects running is asking for trouble. You are likely to crash IE.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realize that such method is not recommended, but I have a program with a BHO, and I really prefer not to ask closing IE or restarting when updating or uninstalling. Isn't there any documented way to ask IE to unload the BHO?

Comment: IE does not expose any API for managing BHOs. Only the user can manage BHOs. The best your program can do is remove the BHO from the Registry and then prompt the user if IE is running, since the BHO is still running in IE's memory.

Comment: That sucks. I mean, how difficult could it be for IE to just expose an `UnloadBHO` function? Anyway, thanks for your help. You might want to post an answer so I'll accept it (although I hoped to accept a different kind of answer).

Comment: If you are to alter specific BHO behavior, then you'd better off writing your BHO to wrap this one and control its lifetime precisely. `FreeLibrary` and friends is nothing but a way towards access violation followed by process crash.

Comment: @RomanR. I thought about something similar. I want to try and go with two dlls - a small BHO wrapper (A), and a library with the functionality (B). (A) would be registered and loaded by IE, and (B) would be loaded by (A). When I e.g. uninstall or update my app, I will notify (A) and it will unload the old (B) and reload the new one. Thus IE wouldn't have to be closed or restarted.